# How to programmatically customise the Contact Form7 notification email prior to sending?

Tags: post-meta, plugin-contact-form-7

I have post_meta that I do not want displayed or accessible in source when viewing a post, but I would like the post_meta to be included in email responses. **How can I achieve this?**

I'm using ACF to create custom fields to generate the post_meta I want and using a hidden field I am able to get an email with the post_meta, but the post_meta is in the page source which isn't ideal.

Comment: are you talking about the notification emali sent when the form is succesfully submitted?

Comment: Yes.When the form is submitted, I would like the data stored in the post_meta ie manager_email sent. But I don't want manager_email displayed in the source of the actual page.

Comment: Contact Form 7, ACF, and other 3rd party plugin/theme dev support is off topic and not in this stacks scope. You should ask via their official support routes or in their groups and communities.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by hooking into the process of the notification mail being sent by the CF7 plugin.  The plugin provides the 'wpcf7_mail_components' [filter](http://hookr.io/plugins/contact-form-7/4.7/filters/wpcf7_mail_components/) which allows you to modify the email message prior to it being sent,

```
add_filter('wpcf7_mail_components','add_mgr_mail',10,3);
function add_mgr_mail($components, $form, $mail_obj){
  //if you have several cf7 forms, check this is the right one,
  if($form->id() != 1) return $components;
  //the components are the in an array...
  $components['subject']; //email subject.
  $components['sender']; //email sender mail.
  $components['body']; //email message body.
  $components['recipient']; //email recipient mails.
  $components['additional_headers']; //email headers.
  $components['attachments']; //email attachments.

  //so, to add your mgr email you could do something like:
  $post_id = .... //fetch the post ID in which you stored your email.
  $mgr_email = get_post_meta($post_id, 'manager_email',true);
  $components['body'] .= PHP_EOL."Manager e-mail:".$mgr_email;
  return $components;
}
```

NOTE: the `$post_id` in the above function represents the ID of the post in which you stored your email.  If the mail is always the same, simply hardcode the email in the above function, however if youe mail depends on the form being submitted then you need to identify the post that contains the right email, but that's a different problem altogether.

Comment: I added this in my functions.php for the theme. I am getting "Manager e-mail:" appended to end of email, but `$mgr_email = get_post_meta($post_id, 'house_manager_email',true);` isn't posting data.

Comment: I tested `$mgr_email = get_post_meta($post_id, 'house_manager_email',true);` in my theme and wasn't able to echo the value. Changing it to `$mgr_email = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'house_manager_email', true );` DID  work in the theme. However it did nothing for the email :(

Comment: the `$post_id` is the id of the post where you stored your email.  If you have only 1 post then hardcode the id value (get it from your dashboard), else if you have multiple posts then you need to identify which post you want to retrieve the email from based on the form being submitted...but that's a different problem altogether.